# Orthogonal non-linear regressions

Tags: r, curve-fitting

I'm trying to fit a non-linear power-law function that follows the equation: *y=b*(x^-a)* using `onls` package.

This is my input data:

```
x <- c(370, 470, 520, 590, 660, 880, 950)
y <- c(11.7, 6.7, 5.31, 4.6, 4.8, 3.2, 1.6)
```

when I use the function `onls()` as in the function example:

```
DAT <- as.data.frame(x, y)
onls(y ~ b1*x^b2, data=DAT, start=list(b1=1000, b2=1))
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = ~y + x, data = DAT) : type (list) 
  incorrect for variable 'y'
```

Comment: Change `DAT = as.data.frame(x, y)` to `DAT = data.frame(x, y)` Right now, R is dropping half the values you passed to `DAT`. You should see something in the console about `row.names` when you run the original function.

Comment: Thank you! Indeed it was a matter of data.class

Answer (score 0):

The data doesn't appear as a power-law. Better try a cubic model :

[image]

If the power-law is definitively wanted, of course a fitting is possible but with much larger deviation :

[image]

Note :
If you use an usual software for non-linear regression the calculus is probably iterative with initial "guessed" values of the parameters. Eventually a bad result might be due to not good enough initial values. Set the ranges of the initial parameters close to the values (a,b) given above (figure 2) and see if the result becomes acceptable.